# eclipse helios xml editor problem

Tags: xml, eclipse, comments

Atually when I used the previous versions of Eclipse I could comment XML blocks just by setting the cursor to the xml element and choosing Source->Block Comment option. Now in Eclipse Helios I'm doing the same, however that action just pastes <!-- --> into the place where the cursor stands. So the block is not actually commented.

Any advice on how to comment it correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: Try highlighting all of the xml you want to be commented and then clicking the Block Comment?

Comment: That works. Thanks! However is there a way of commenting in old style?

Comment: Please see my answer (might be which Helios you have?) and remember to accept as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Highlight all of the xml you want to be commented and then click the Block Comment. I am not too sure why it would not be working in Helios (are you using the [Java EE version](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr2) ?) I currently use MyEclipse for Spring and it works the old way so it might be that you have a basic version of Helios that doesn't have that capability?